# Change application's name without touching the default activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android application with a default activity which is defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:label="NameOfMyApp"
    ...

    <activity
                android:name=".LoginActivity"
                android:label="Login">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.rei0d.wop.MainActivity" />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

It seems that `android:label="NameOfMyApp"` will be overwritten if there is an attribut `android:label` for the default activity.

So I want to change the application's name to something else than `Login`, `NameOfMyApp` for example, without changing the `android:label` of the `Login` activity. Is this possible? Or do I have to create a blanc activity as default activity which starts the `Login` activity?

Comment: You can use Strings.xml and get your application name from there

Comment: I know, but this doens't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are multiple possibilities to fix this issue, unfortunately some of them don’t work on all devices.
It seems like that the Launcher takes the application-name from the label of the "Entry Activity". You can prevent his by adding the following attribute to your intent-filer:

```
<intent-filter android:label="NameOfMyApp">
```

Unfortunately some Launchers may ignore this, so I wouldn’t go for this solution.

I would recommend you to change the title of your Login-Activity programatically. So first of all change the `android:label` value of your `.LoginActivity` to the name of your app.
In onCreate or somewhere else set the title (assuming that you’re using the ActionBar).

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Login");
```

*Note: You should get the title from a strings-xml file of course*

Comment: Thanks, I've done `setTitle("Login");` because it seems that `getActionBar().setTitle("Login");` doens't work properly with API level 10. Now it works! :)

Comment: That's right. The ActionBar was added in Android 3.0 (API Level 11), so on previous version you can't call getActionBar() safely ;)